# How to handle this Excel validation quirk?

Tags: excel, validation, vba

I have this code. It's contrived code for the sake of the example.

```
Sub x()
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Validation.Delete
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateCustom, Formula1:="=VALUE(RIGHT(A1,6))>0"
End Sub
```

If A1 is blank when the code executes, I get an error 1004, application-defined or object-defined error. I believe it's because the formula results in `#VALUE!` instead of `False`. If I try to set the validation manually, I get a warning that the result is an error, but if I click OK, the validation then works normally.

I figured it was because I was not exempting blank cells from validation, so I added the line:

```
Sub x()
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Validation.Delete
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Validation.IgnoreBlank = True
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateCustom, Formula1:="=VALUE(RIGHT(A1,6))>0"
End Sub
```

But that just shifted the error up one line. Now I get the 1004 error on the `IgnoreBlank = True` line.

I suppose I could temporarily enter a value into the cell, set validation, and then delete the contents of the cell, but I'm hoping there's a different way.

Am I doing something wrong? I was originally planning on validating programmatically at the end instead of using Excel's validation feature.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear you cannot set `IgnoreBlank` before you `Add` something, at which point it's too late.

Other than your own workaround idea (and variations thereof, e.g. setting validation to a formula that is always `TRUE`, flipping the `IgnoreBlank` and changing the formula to the real one), you could also handle blank cells in the validation formula itself:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A1), TRUE, VALUE(RIGHT(A1,6))>0)
```